# Keyboard shortcuts for closing WebBrowser in WinForms won't work

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I have a usercontrol in which I have placed a WebBrowser as an editor. I would like to be able to use `Ctrl` + `Enter` to close the form, which I'm already able to do when focus is on either the RichTextControl usercontrol or the TagPage control. (See image 1 for Document Outline - WebBrowser is added to `tabPageEdit` in the code.) My problem is, that `Ctrl` + `Enter` won't work when  the WebBrowser is focused.

My working code in the class `RichTextControl.cs`:

```
void RichTextControl_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        close();
    }
}

void tabControlEdit_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if( e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        close();
    }
}
```

In my class `RichEditor.cs` which is the WebBrowser, I have tried to override the `ProcessCmdKey()` method using the same implementation as in `RichTextControl.cs`, but it does not work.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    KeyEventArgs e = new KeyEventArgs(keyData);
    if( e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        richTextControl.close();
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

The statement `e.Modifiers == Keys.Control` is always true, but `e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter` is never true, because `e.KeyCode == ControlKeys`. What am I doing wrong here?

Image 1:

[image]

Comment: WebBrowser has to negotiate with its host to determine which one gets the keystroke.  Important because any Javascript that runs in the browser sees keystrokes as well.  You are doing battle with [this code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/WebBrowser.cs,1834).  Click through to Shortcut to see that Ctrl+Enter is not.  So ProcessCmdKey() can't see it.  Google "webbrowser custom idochostuihandler" to get ahead.

Comment: I don't know if it makes any difference, but inside my WebBrowser I am using a version of TinyMCE.

Comment: It doesn't.  Do consider the standard shortcut to close a window, the one that the user knows.  Unlike Ctrl+Enter, they'll only hit that one by accident and probably won't be happy when they do.  It is Alt+F4.

Comment: Ctrl+Enter is a consistent shortcut in my program to close and save editors, so the users will know, but thanks for the advise!